# How to get selected checkbox from GridView::widget in controller without using jquery?

Tags: jquery, yii2

i am using yii2 framework and i'm trainee.
i want to ask you that i'm using Gridview::widget on index.php, now i have one button for multiple-delete and multiple-status change, and its working fine with jquery ajax,but i want to pass selected checkbox id to controller/action directly without using jquery.
can any one please help me?
if anyone want it through jquery ajax, then i have attached the code you can use that, but i want without jquery-ajax.
please help.
thanks,
Hunny Malhotra.

```js
my controller code:
//multiple delete action
    public function actionDeletem()
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $model = users::find()->where(['in','user_id',$id])->all();
        foreach($model as $data){
            $data->deleted = 'Y';
            $data->save();
        }
        echo "Deleted";
    }

    //multiple change status action
    public function actionStatusm()
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $model = users::find()->where(['in','user_id',$id])->all();
        foreach($model as $data) {
            if($data->status == 1){
                $data->status = 0;
                $data->save();
            }else if($data->status == 0){
                $data->status = 1;
                $data->save();
            }
        }
        echo "Status Changed Successfully";
    }
```

```html
below is my index.php code with jqoery code init:

<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Url;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel backend\models\UsersSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Manage Users';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = 'Users';
?>
<div class="users-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode('Users') ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<?php
    $user = Yii::$app->user->identity->user_type;
    if($user == 1)
    { ?>
        <p>
            <?= Html::a('Create User', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
            <input type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" value='Delete'>
            <input type="button" id="status" class="btn btn-primary" value='Status'>
            <?= Html::a('Export to Excel', ['excel'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info']) ?>
            <?= Html::a('Import File', ['import'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
            <?= Html::a('Test', ['test'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        </p>
<?php } ?>

<?php Pjax::begin(['id'=>'users']); ?>  <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                'visible'  => $user == 1 ? true : false,
                'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                    return ['value' => $model['user_id'] ];
                }
            ],
            'user_id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email:email',
            'mobile',
            [
                'attribute' =>  'status',
                'label'     =>  'Status',
                'filter'    =>  Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'status', [1=>'Active',0=>'Inactive'],            ['prompt' => 'All']),
                                'value'     => function($model) {
                                    return $model->status == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';
                                },
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'created_on',
                'value' => 'created_on',
                'filter' => \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget(['model'=>$searchModel,'attribute'=>'created_on','language'=>'en',
                    'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',]),
                'format' => 'html'
            ],
            'created_by',
            [   
                'class'    => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'visible'  => $user == 1 ? true : false,
                'header' => 'Action',
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'color:#3c8dbc'],
            ],
        ],
    ]);?>

<?php Pjax::end(); ?></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#delete').click(function(){
            var id = $('#w0').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
            console.log(id);
            if(id<1) {
                alert("No Rows are Selected");
                
            }else{
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['users/deletem']); ?>",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {id: id},
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                            $.pjax.reload({container:'#users'});
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        $('#status').click(function(){
            var id = $('#w0').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
            if(id<1) {
                alert("No Rows are Selected");
            }else{    
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['users/statusm']); ?>",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {id: id},
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                        $.pjax.reload({container:'#users'});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: and in above code, if any code optimization will also help.

Comment: how can i get the selected value for a radiobutton instead of a checkbox?